# how to customize an application according to city

Tags: android

I would like to customize my application according to city name, for example if we have `X` and `Y` cities name ,I want to show some offers to people from `X` city, and different offers to people from `Y` city.

I must get city name in the splash screen that it's displayed for 3 seconds.(because after it there is a `ListView` to show my offers).

what is the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
if (addresses.size() > 0) 
    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
```

That prints the name of the current city. Then you can store that and use it to check for offers, or other data that you want.

Edit: You have to provide the "getFromLocation" with the current coordinates of the user, ofcourse.

Comment: Yup. Probably no way around using GPS if you want that type of functionality. Another solution could be to use a third-party site or API that checks for the current city using the IP adress, though. But if you're on a cell phone that really might not be very reliable.